# How to put json dictionary into a numpy recarray or structured array

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, numpy

I need to put json dictionary into a numpy record or structured array. The reason is the data comes in random column order in json and i cannot append new data rows. Also cannot use panda due to memory limitations from the size of data.

How do I do this?

Example:
data coming in:
[{'time':18:00, 'name':'bob' ,'likes':'icecream'}, {}, {}, ....]

I've got something like this:

```
x = np.array(raw.json())
b = []
for i in range (0,len(x)):
      b.append(list(x[i].items()))
bb = np.array(b)

#flattens an extra dimension 
data = bb[:,:,1] 
names = nn[0,:,0]
```

from purely going by the shapes and experimenting with the results. is there a better way of getting this into a single 2D structured array or recarray?

Comment: To make a structured array you either need to supply the data as a list of tuples (one per row/record), or create a "zeros" array of the right length and dtype, and assign values field by field.

Answer (score 0):

A sample list derived from a `json` string:

```
In [89]: alist = [{'time':'18:00', 'name':'bob' ,'likes':'icecream', 'age':10}]
In [90]: alist
Out[90]: [{'time': '18:00', 'name': 'bob', 'likes': 'icecream', 'age': 10}]
```

Set up a "blank" array with desired fields (names and dtype):

```
In [91]: arr = np.zeros(1, dtype=[('time','U10'),('name','U10'),('likes','U10'),('age',int)])
In [92]: arr
Out[92]: 
array([('', '', '', 0)],
      dtype=[('time', '<U10'), ('name', '<U10'), ('likes', '<U10'), ('age', '<i8')])
```

On second thought, it may be easier to create the list of tuples (assuming all `dict` has the same key orders):

```
In [93]: [tuple(x.values()) for x in alist]
Out[93]: [('18:00', 'bob', 'icecream', 10)]
In [94]: barr = np.array(_, arr.dtype)
In [95]: barr
Out[95]: 
array([('18:00', 'bob', 'icecream', 10)],
      dtype=[('time', '<U10'), ('name', '<U10'), ('likes', '<U10'), ('age', '<i8')])
```

Setting values, row by row, field by field:

```
In [96]: for i,adict in enumerate(alist):
    ...:     for key in adict.keys():
    ...:         arr[key][i] = adict[key]
    ...: 
In [97]: arr
Out[97]: 
array([('18:00', 'bob', 'icecream', 10)],
      dtype=[('time', '<U10'), ('name', '<U10'), ('likes', '<U10'), ('age', '<i8')])
```

With the json structure we have to process each `dict` separately, so setting all rows of `arr` with one field at a time isn't practical.

===

After playing with dataframes in a different SO, I realized that making a frame from a json list is easy:

```
In [140]: data = [{'time':'18:00', 'name':'bob' ,'likes':'icecream', 'age':10
     ...: }]
In [141]: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[141]: 
    time name     likes  age
0  18:00  bob  icecream   10
In [142]: pd.DataFrame(data*5)
Out[142]: 
    time name     likes  age
0  18:00  bob  icecream   10
1  18:00  bob  icecream   10
2  18:00  bob  icecream   10
3  18:00  bob  icecream   10
4  18:00  bob  icecream   10
```

I don't think going first to a structured array will save memory (compared to a direct to pandas).  But I don't like to test memory limits.